# I want to link matching text using easy autocomplete jquery plunging

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, autocomplete

Hi guys I face a problem with easy autocomplete jquery plunging.

I have successfully installed this in my site but I have a simple issue.
[i want link this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9BTTY.png)
I want link this with a external herf link.When user type and click here the go to the external.

```js
//Enable description function  
var options = {
    url: "json/linked.json",
    
    getValue: "text",

    template: {
        type: "links",
        type: "description",
        fields: {
            link: "website-link",
            description: "realName"
        }
    },

    theme: "bootstrap"
};

 $("#sheroes").easyAutocomplete(options);
```

```html
[
 {
  "text": "Home",
        "realName": "Jahid Hasan",
  "website-link": "http://localhost/test/test.php"
 },
 {
  "text": "Guide",
  "website-link": "http://localhost/test/test.php"
 },
 {
  "text": "Themes",
        "realName": "Bruce Wayne",
  "website-link": "http://localhost/test/test.php"
 },
 {
  "text": "Examples",
  "website-link": "http://localhost/test/test.php"
 },
 {
  "text": "Download",
  "website-link": "http://localhost/test/test.php"
 },
 {
  "text": "Github",
  "website-link": "http://localhost/test/test.php"
 }
]
```

how i can do it.
Advance thanks

Comment: Please provide code examples.

Comment: pastebin.com/embed_js/hzFWzkQK

Comment: http://jahidweb.boxhost.me/fiverr/test/test.php see the result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just call window.open method, when user will change the text.

```
$("#sheroes"). change( function(){ 
  $.getJSON("result.json", function(data){ 
     $.each(data, function(i){
       if(data[i].text==$("#sheroes").val()) {
          window.open(data[i].website_link); 
       } 
     }); 
   }); 
});
```

Comment: pastebin.com/embed_js/hzFWzkQK

Comment: Hey Jahid. Can you please upload your easyAutoComplete jquery on server. So that we could use it as url.

Comment: see my cod above have any problem there?

Comment: Actually I am unable to get that easyAutocomplete jquery. I need that jquery src. That's why I am saying to upload it on server.

Comment: try this code @Jahid.                                                                                    `$("#sheroes"). change( function(){
 $.getJSON("result.json", function(data){
  $.each(data, function(i){
   if(data[i].text == $("#sheroes").val()){
    window.open(data[i].website_link);
   }
  });
 });
});`

Comment: Hi it's worked but it open a new window when click.Have there any way to load this on same window  and thank you so much

Comment: Just add target in window.open as "_self".  i.e. `window.open(data[i].website_link,"_self");`  and don't forget to vote

Comment: Ohh yes i forgot it.Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You can add URL in your JSON or Data and bind with element through autocomplete and call External API or link like this..

```
$('#scheme').on('autocompleteselect', function (e, ui) 
{  //pass selected value to function    
  doSearch(ui.item.value);
}
```

function to redirect to external link

```
function doSearch(location) {
    window.location.href = location;
}
```

Comment: my code pastebin.com/embed_js/hzFWzkQK see it please